# How to get gas station along my route in Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api

I have an application that draws route between origin and destination.
I need to mark gas stations on this route.
I have read the google places API.
Can you give me idea how to use places API in this case?

Answer (score 2):

1st you need google map api key.. You can get one from google.. check out
[this link](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/).
Now when you have api key... you can use it to get your desired places using
[this link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=Your_Latitude,Your_Longitude&radius=In_Metres&types=What_You_Want_To_Search&key=Your_API_KEY)
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=Your_Latitude,Your_Longitude&radius=In_Metres&types=What_You_Want_To_Search&key=Your_API_KEY

and for type of places support.. check out [this link](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle Categorical search fr this.You can have detail knowledge in

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intents
```

If you pass a general search term, Google Maps will attempt to find a location near the lat/lng you specified that matches your criteria. If no location is specified, Google Maps will try to find nearby listings. For example:

```
// Search for restaurants nearby
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=restaurants");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);


// Search for restaurants in San Francisco
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194?q=restaurants");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

you can do in similar way for gas station

Comment: I checked it. In this case will open google maps( official app) - it doesn't approach for me. In me app I have 2 text fields for origin and destination and button(Load directions) and when i press button i need to mark gas station on my built route

Comment: i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/) tutorial. You might find this helpful

```
GooglePlaces.java
package com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleHeaders;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpParser;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class GooglePlaces {

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

    // Google API Key
    private static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyCRLa4LQZWNQBcjCYcIVYA45i9i8zfClqc";

    // Google Places serach url's
    private static final String PLACES_SEARCH_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
    private static final String PLACES_TEXT_SEARCH_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
    private static final String PLACES_DETAILS_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?";

    private double _latitude;
    private double _longitude;
    private double _radius;

    /**
     * Searching places
     * @param latitude - latitude of place
     * @params longitude - longitude of place
     * @param radius - radius of searchable area
     * @param types - type of place to search
     * @return list of places
     * */
    public PlacesList search(double latitude, double longitude, double radius, String types)
            throws Exception {

        this._latitude = latitude;
        this._longitude = longitude;
        this._radius = radius;

        try {

            HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
            HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                    .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));
            request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
            request.getUrl().put("location", _latitude + "," + _longitude);
            request.getUrl().put("radius", _radius); // in meters
            request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");
            if(types != null)
                request.getUrl().put("types", types);

            PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
            // Check log cat for places response status
            Log.d("Places Status", "" + list.status);
            return list;

        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Searching single place full details
     * @param refrence - reference id of place
     *                 - which you will get in search api request
     * */
    public PlaceDetails getPlaceDetails(String reference) throws Exception {
        try {

            HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
            HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                    .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_DETAILS_URL));
            request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
            request.getUrl().put("reference", reference);
            request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");

            PlaceDetails place = request.execute().parseAs(PlaceDetails.class);

            return place;

        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            Log.e("Error in Perform Details", e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creating http request Factory
     * */
    public static HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(
            final HttpTransport transport) {
        return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
                GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
                headers.setApplicationName("AndroidHive-Places-Test");
                request.setHeaders(headers);
                JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory());
                request.addParser(parser);
            }
        });
    }

}
```